# Is possible in Azure DevOps publish artefacts to anyone on the internet but hide source code at the same time?

Tags: azure-devops, devops, feed, public

Is possible in Azure Devops, publish artefacts to anyone in the internet and hide source code at the same time ? For example, using Public feeds ?
I tried this possibility but cannot push to public feed from private project and I dont want show source code of my project (if the project was public).

Answer (score 0):

> Is possible in Azure DevOps publish artefacts to anyone on the internet but hide source code at the same time?

If you want to publish artefacts to anyone in the internet and hide source code at the same time, you need to build the project and publish the binaries or compiled product to the public feed.

Indeed, we could not push to public feed from private project. But we could publish to the public feed from local with client tools.

Besides, in order not to leak your source code, you need exclude the source code from the artifact, like those packages in the nuget.org, it only include the dll files in the package.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance, we started publish .NET nugets to mentioned public feed in Azure DevOps.